# Where is 'package:firebase/wrapper.dart'?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am making a flutter application. I am integrating firebase as my database. I am looking for the 'wrapper.dart' file in the firebase package. I have it installed and in my dependencies. but I can't find the file.

Comment: What makes you think that that file is supposed to exist?

Comment: @jamesdlin I am following a tutorial. https://medium.com/@lumeilin301/flutter-firebase-app-tutorial-part-2-app-structure-5f613b72ad2d

Comment: Skimming over that tutorial, it seems like `firebase` is the name of the *app* you're creating, not a third-party package, and `wrapper.dart` is a file *you* are supposed to create.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for helping me realize this silly problem